# app.all(*) returns entrire html even on post request

Tags: node.js, express

I am using `app.all(*)` in my express route to send `pagenotfound.html` page. So at the end of all of my routes, I have:

```
app.all('*',security.isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("pageNotFound.ejs")
})
```

I was sending a post request using jquery ajax and found out that if the route to the post request does not exist it will send the entire html page to my success callback function.

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"/urlThatDoesNotExist",
  success:function(data){
     //data = ENTIRE HTML FILE
  }
})
```

I know I can change my catch all in express to send something like:

```
res.status(404).json({
            status: 'fail',
            message: `Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`
         })
```

But that would mean that I cannot show themthe pageNotFound.html page.

Is there a way to catch all post route and catch all get route separately? I am not sure how you guys handle it in your application.

Comment: Handle your API calls in a different router and then handle unknown routes differently in each router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use app.use().
All you need to do is to put this at the end of all your routes and handle it there.
You can check which method is it with the req.method and then handle it.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET')
    handleGet()
  else if (req.method === 'POST')
    handlePost()
  else 
    handleRequests()
})
```